# Freestanding Pergola with 2x12x15ft beams need knee braces to prevent sagging?

Tags: beam, pergola

I built a freestanding pergola on my existing pool deck. I used pressure-treated lumber, ( southern pine ) eight 6x6 posts sandwiched with 2x12 beams that span approx. 15ft, 14ft and 10ft.

All bolted with 1/2 bolts and then topped with notched 2x8 rafters that vary in length from 9ft to 12ft. I will also be adding metal roofing panels ( *with non-treated 2x4 running parallel with the beams atop the rafters* ).

I live in central Texas, so no concern for snow load.

My question is whether or not I need to add knee braces to keep the 15ft and 14ft spans from sagging over time ?

[image: Pic of actual pergola built]

Thanks,
Brent

Comment: Try out https://www.awc.org/codes-standards/calculators-software/spancalc. Overall, you won't regret over-engineering it.

Comment: Brent, can you provide info on the metal panels you're installing? I need to know how much they weigh per square foot or their total weight and panel dimensions.

Comment: If it is necessary, I think i would rather have additional vertical posts mid span then a bunch of knee braces at head height.

Comment: **St Peter**, "*how did you die*" ? **You**, "*i was getting out of  the pool and while drying my hair with a towel i stood up and hit my head on the knee brace rendering me unconscious as fell backwards into the pool and drown*". **St Peter**, "*sorry i can not let you in*".

Comment: The perlins for your metal roofing do not need to be 2x4's. 1x2's will be sufficient. 2x2's would also work.